# React - bundle.js not found (using Nginx setup)

Tags: reactjs, nginx, deployment

I have a React app set up to run on port 8080. When I run the deployed project using `http://example.com:8080`, it runs well.

However, I'm using nginx to proxy this url, adding the "location /admins" to **etc/nginx/nginx.conf**:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

location /admins {
    proxy_pass "http://hadas-ex.co.il:8080";
}
```

Then, when browsing to `hadas.ex.co.il/admins`, it serves the app, but I get the following error in my console:

> GET http://hadas-ex.co.il/static/js/bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

I'm just confused as to why I'm getting this error, as it's working fine when accessing the `hadas-ex.co.il:8080` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Port **80** and Port **8080** are not the same. **Ports** are used to make connections unique and range from 0 to 65535 out of which upto 1024 are called well known **ports** which are reserved by convention to identify specific service types on a host. **80** is reserved for HTTP. **Port 8080** is typically used for a personally hosted web server, when the ISP restricts this type of usage for non-commercial customers. **Port 8080** is the just the default second choice for a webserver.

#### Resources:

- [Are-port-80-and-8080-the-same](https://www.quora.com/Are-port-80-and-8080-the-same)
- [Apache-httpd-vs-tomcat-7-port-80-vs-port-8080](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17313661/apache-httpd-vs-tomcat-7-port-80-vs-port-8080)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Daniel, but of course they are not the same, my intention is to use port 8080 for the second project. The first project works on the default port 80 and the second one is on port 8080 as shown in the code. And it's working totally fine! I would just like to use the url mysite.com/admins instead of using the port name.
And that is what's not working for me.
Do you know why I get this error?
Thanks

Comment: Which application send request to ```http://hadas-ex.co.il/static/js/bundle.js``` ? ```localhost``` or ```http://hadas-ex.co.il:8080``` ?

Comment: Meybe ```http://hadas-ex.co.il:8080/``` send requests relative to host and then you must configure this application.